# Make a table's field in MongoDB text searchable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**Prerequisites**:

Database is created already with the collections **posts** and it's Schema is as follows:

```
module.exports = function(mongoose){
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var postSchema = new Schema({
   postID:          String,
   title:           String,
   description:     String
});

mongoose.model('post', postSchema, 'posts');
postSchema.index({title: 'text'});

};
```

Node's router to handle via an API:

```
apiRouter.get('/api/searchPosts', function(req, res, next){
    postModel.find(
        { $text : { $search : req.query.text } }, 
        { score : { $meta: "textScore" } }
    )
    .sort({ score : { $meta : 'textScore' } })
    .exec(function(err, posts) {
        if(posts){
            res.json({
                posts       :   posts
            });
        } else {
            res.send('Post does not exist');
        }
    });
});
```

**What I am trying to achieve:**

I want to make a field in my **posts** table called **title** text searchable.

**My stack:**

MongoDB, NodeJS (with Mongoose), Angular

**My approach:**

As mentioned in the Prerequisites, I have added the line:

```
postSchema.index({title: 'text'});
```

Furthermore, I have run the below command in the terminal once the collections has been created:

```
db.posts.createIndex({"title":"text"})
```

**The problem**:

When I access this from the URL, it works initially but after a few weeks, it stops working (I get 'Post does not exist' without making any changes!). To get it working again, I have to delete the collections and make a fresh one and run the command:

```
db.posts.createIndex({"title":"text"})
```

It then starts working for a few weeks and so on.

What I am doing wrong? I am not seeing a trend about what happens in these few weeks. I have been stuck on this issue for a few weeks so if someone can help, it will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Shayan

Comment: What I would do there, is instead of returning that 'Post does not exists', I would return something from that err (which I assume is the actual error). Maybe you are getting a timeout or something like this. Any mongo logs to check and so on?

Comment: Great suggestion with the error. I have been involved in development for just under a year so excuse the noob mistake.

The 'err' was: The error is: MongoError: text index required for $text query - but I have already done that. Somehow, the mondoDB itself has forgotten I have run the command. I will see if there's anything in the logs as well.

Comment: Hey @AndreiNeagu - I have posted my answer below. Thanks for the suggestion. I will keep this post updated if anything breaks again for future viewers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, the solution was as below:

```
var postSchema = new Schema({
  postID:          String,
  title:           { type: String, text: true },
  description:     String
});
```

This did the trick so far.

I will check this again and see if it breaks like it did every few weeks. Will update the post if it does.

Thanks Andrei Neagu for the logging the 'err' suggestion. Sometimes, the obvious ones just get missed

Comment: you're welcome. so, what was the actual error message that you got ?

Comment: This was the error message: The error is: MongoError: text index required for $text query. 

What is bizarre is that it WAS working when I created a new table/collection called 'posts' and ran the command: db.posts.createIndex({"title":"text"}) in terminal> mongo. However, it stopped working every couple of weeks.

Comment: I will be keeping an eye on this and will update my post if there are any changes.

Comment: Working till today. This was the solution. Hope this helps someone.