# MongoDB index search works in console, but not from browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, indexing, mongoose

All of this was working yesterday so I'm really not sure whats wrong.  I'v searched on SO and been through the docs and steps a number of times but I havnt got it to work.  Any help much appreciated as always!

If I type `db.movies.find({ '$text': { '$search': 'elephant' } })` into the shell, it returns a list of titles with 'elephant' in the title.  But if I run the same search from my browser it crashes the node server and I get `MongoError: text index required for $text query`.

The error comes from the error response from the `find()`:

```
Movie.find(
  { '$text': { '$search': 'elephants' } },
  (err, movies) => {
    if (err) throw err; // MongoError: text index required for $text query
    if (!movies) {
      res.json({
        data: null,
        success: false,
        message: 'No movies data'
      });
    } else {
      res.json({
        success: true,
        data: movies
      });
    }
  })
```

The index on my DB looks like this:

```
{
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_fts" : "text",
            "_ftsx" : 1
        },
        "name" : "title_text",
        "ns" : "db.movies",
        "weights" : {
            "title" : 1
        },
        "default_language" : "english",
        "language_override" : "language",
        "textIndexVersion" : 3
    }
```

I also have mongoose schemas defined and I'm using an auto increment plugin to increment a custom `id` field on each movie save.  (Saving movies works, so I am connecting to the DB ok)

```
  mongoose.model('Job', new Schema({
    id: Number,
    title: String,
    desc: String,
    genre: String
  })
  .index({ title: 'text' })
  .plugin(autoIncrement.mongoosePlugin));
```

Comment: What is the second set of parameters `{ score... }` for?

Comment: the `find()` has a `.sort()` which uses the `$meta: 'textScore'`, which also has to be defined as an arg in the find.  I'll update the question to include that full object instead of the variable

Comment: Have you run the exact same query in the shell (with sorting)?

Comment: You stated that you can run the query in the shell, but didn't mention the second parameter object you pass to `Movie.find`. Could that be giving you problems?

Comment: Cheers for the input @ChrisSatchell, I removed that 2nd param and still get the same error.  So I'v removed it from my question example too.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41658592/make-a-tables-field-in-mongodb-text-searchable

Comment: @ChrisSatchell you are an absolute legend.  That worked!  I actually tried something similar a while ago but I had a stupid mistake of `index:true` instead of `text:true` which threw me. Thanks a lot for your solving this!

Comment: @ChrisSatchell you are an absolute legend.  That worked!  I actually tried something similar a while ago but I had a stupid mistake of `index:true` instead of `text:true` which threw me. Thanks a lot for your solving this!

Comment: Glad it worked, still seems rather odd though. But hey, what would programming be like without the odd quirk or two

Comment: It is a strange one, well lets hope your answer helps others. good work!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments by @Chris Satchell
Adding the index to the mongoose schema solves this.

instead of:

```
mongoose.model('Job', new Schema({
    id: Number,
    title: String,
    desc: String,
    genre: String
  })
```

do this:

```
mongoose.model('Job', new Schema({
    id: Number,
    title: { type: String, text: true },
    desc: String,
    genre: String
  })
```

even though I still had `.index({ title: 'text' })` on the Schema, you still need to define the `{ type: String, text: true }` on the property.